# how to send string in my append html function in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am returning data from controller, and i use a ajax call over there

```
 $singleArray['traveller'] = json_encode($traveller); //get data from own array
    $finalDataArray[] =  $singleArray; // assigen data to global array
    return ['status'=>'true','flightResults'=> $finalDataArray] //return data to ajax call
```

In my *jquery* part i use `foreach` loop and pass to append html.

In append html have a button

```
onclick=testfunction(\'' + item.traveller + '\')
```

I pass the data which i get from `foreach` loop.

now i want to send data to the function in jquery, I create a function `testfunction`:

```
function testfunction(travller)
{
    console.log(travller); //want to get which array is $traveller valriable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `onclick=testfunction(\'' + item.traveller + '\')` to `onclick=testfunction('\' + item.traveller + '\')`